# edit vs. approve edit

Tags: discussion, editing, review, suggested-edits

I find it amusing that as a high rep user I can edit a post without asking for approval, but if I review an edit proposed by somebody else I can't approve it finally.  It still needs approval from other readers.  My most recent example was [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641274/how-to-integrate-e1-n-n2#641274) where there was an edit to the body that should have been copied to the title but wasn't.  I approved the edit, but wanted to fix the title.  Unfortunately, the edit was still pending, so I couldn't fix the title.  Should this be fixed?

Comment: When reviewing suggested edits, you should have the option of _improving_ the edit.

Comment: I do, but if I am happy with it as is, my approve vote is not sufficient to approve it.  My point is that if I did the same edit myself, it would be approved without anybody else seeing it.  If I approve it, it still needs other approvals.  This seems inconsistent.  If somebody who could make a unilateral edit approves somebody else's edit, it should be approved.

Comment: Is your gravatar suddenly different than before?

Comment: I am sure there were several discussion of this on meta.SO. By quick search I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180682/why-are-two-approvals-needed-for-a-suggested-edits-to-be-applied and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94581/instant-edit-approval-for-high-rep-users

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Not that I know of.  It looks the same to me, but without the December hat.

Answer (score 11):

I disagree that this is a bug, or even an issue.

The act of "reviewing" an edit is/can be much less time/effort consuming (if you catch my drift) than the act of making an actual edit. Approving an edit also gives +2 reputation to the user who proposed the edit.

The situations are clearly not symmetric.

Hence there exists additional check and balances (in addition to the two-user review system, also the occasional "test questions") to counteract gaming of the system.

> Putting it bluntly: the system may trust you *not* to vandalise a post, but that doesn't mean that the system trusts you to be able to spot it when someone vandalised a post.

Comment: I hate the "test questions". I "passed" all the tests up until now, but I certainly did not think that all of them were so clear-cut that every reasonable person has to agree that they are bad.

Comment: I was just about to add an answer of my own when I noticed your spoiler-protected hint. I think that is *really* a reason to require another reviewwer even after a high-rep approver.

Answer (score 4):

There is definitely a missing feature here. After a user has selected "approve", they should be able to change their mind and edit the post instead.

I will post this as a feature request.